# Generate Schema using gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, jooq

```
 Jdbc getJdbc() {
        return new Jdbc().withDriver("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                .withUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ztbl")
                .withUsername("")
               .withPassword("");
    }
    Database getDatabase() {
        return new Database()
                .withName("org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase")
                .withSchemata(
                        new SchemaMappingType().withInputSchema("ztbl").withOutputSchema("bpc"),
                        new SchemaMappingType().withInputSchema("tes_inbound").withOutputSchema("ib"),
                        new SchemaMappingType().withInputSchema("tesoutbound").withOutputSchema("ob"),
                        new SchemaMappingType().withInputSchema("tesob_calling").withOutputSchema("obcall"),
                        new SchemaMappingType().withInputSchema("hosting").withOutputSchema("cms"),
                        new SchemaMappingType().withInputSchema("hosting_new").withOutputSchema("cmm"),
                        new SchemaMappingType().withInputSchema("hosting_new").withOutputSchema("cmm")
                        //new SchemaMappingType().withInputSchema("stats").withOutputSchema("stats")
                );
    }
```

Hi i'm new generate jooq schema with gradle, previously i was using maven to generate jooq schema, but currently i'm shift on gradle and i don't know how to generate jooq schema.i had this code on my genSchema project.i'm trying to find how to generate this schema any help please.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? And are you using / aware of this third party plugin? https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin

Comment: "error: package db.ib does not exist"

Actually i'm getting this error whenever i'm trying to run the project